# Editing metadata of H.264 MP4 videos

Tags: metadata, mp4, h.264

Windows [lets me edit some metadata fields](http://cisftp.kirtland.edu/cis210/Week7/images/video-properties.jpg) of H.264 encoded videos, such as “Title” and “Comments.” Such data seem to be preserved inside the file itself, which is what I want.

Some applications make use of a field called “Description,” and I have found no way of adding this metadata field to H.264 videos. iTunes lets users edit this video field, but unfortunately doesn’t seem able to process H.264 MP4 videos at all.

What’s the most effective approach when it comes to editing metadata of already existing H.264-encoded MP4 files?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the fields can be filled in using [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) as follows:

```
MP4Box -itags writer=me file.mp4
```

You can have a list of supported tags with `MP4Box -tag-list`. If some fields are not supported, [file an issue](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues).

Answer (score 2):

As of version 11.39, [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) has the ability to edit tags in MP4/Mov files. To edit the tags listed in this question, the command would be

```
exiftool -Title="New Title" -Description="New Description" -Comment="New Comment" file.mp4
```

This command creates backup files. Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files. Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

See [exiftool's Quicktime Tag page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html) for a list of the tags that exiftool can edit.